# Customize JQuery Mobile ListView with Box Shadow and Border

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I am trying to apply a box shadow and border to my images in JQuery Mobile ListView.  I want the result to look like the attachment below.  I have not been able to successfully apply it directly to the img attribute.

Here is the css I am using for the box shadow.

```
.effect2
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before, .effect2:after
{
   z-index: -1;
   position: absolute;
   content: "";
   bottom: 15px;
   left: 10px;
   width: 50%;
   top: 80%;
   max-width:300px;
   background: #777;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
   box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-theme="b">
          <li data-theme="">
              <a href="#history" data-transition="none" >
              <img class="box effect2" src="img/History-thumb.jpg"/>
                  <h3>History</h3>
                  <p>A Brief History of Beaufort</p>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li data-theme="">
              <a href="#featured" data-transition="none">
                <img src="img/Featured.jpg"/>
                  <h3>Featured</h3>
                  <p>Featured Local Businesses and Restaurants</p>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li data-theme="">
              <a href="#restaurants" data-transition="none">
              <img src="img/FrogmoreStew-thumb.jpg"/>
                  <h3>Restaurants</h3>
                  <p>Local Restaurants and Dining</p>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li data-theme="">
              <a href="#shopping" data-transition="none">
                <img src="img/Shopping.jpg"/>
                  <h3>Shopping</h3>
                  <p>Shopping in Downtown</p>
              </a>
          </li>       
      </ul>
```

Thanks,

Robert

[image]

Comment: Add html markup of the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<img>` element does not support the :before and :after pseudo elements in most browsers, so you have to use a little more complex HTML and CSS.  One way is to surround the thumbnail in a containing `<div>` and apply the page curl effect to the it.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-theme="a">
    <li class="ui-li-has-thumb">
        <a href="#history" data-transition="none" >
             <div class="page-curl">
                 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/city/1/"/>
             </div>
             <h3>History</h3>
             <p>A Brief History of Beaufort</p>
         </a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Add the class ui-li-has-thumb to the `<li>` element so that padding will be added to the left allowing room for the image. Then surrround the image with a container and apply a class to it (page-curl in my example).  Then add the page curl CSS:

```
.page-curl {
    background: white;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.page-curl img{
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 72px;
    max-height: 72px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.page-curl:before, .page-curl:after {
    background: none;
    bottom: 11px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    content: "";
    height: 10px;
    left: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    z-index: -1;
    -moz-transform: skew(-4deg) rotate(-4deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-4deg) rotate(-4deg);
    transform: skew(-4deg) rotate(-4deg);
}

.page-curl:after {
    -moz-transform: skew(4deg) rotate(4deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(4deg) rotate(4deg);
    transform: skew(4deg) rotate(4deg);
    left: auto;
    right: 6px;
}
```

Tweak to taste.

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yq2afa0j/)**

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was able to tweak it a little more and make it stand out the way I wanted with the white border.